# TF: Create mask from binary data read (item assignment)

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Problem**

I'm reading data from a binary database and part of that data are coordinates (x,y) within an image mask and the image itself. The mask itself is easy to create when I know the image shape and the coordinates. Basically I just have to create an empty mask with the shape defined by the image read and set the pixel to one at the given coordinates. So what I basically want is something like the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# coord read from binary file
x = tf.constant([1])
y = tf.constant([1])

# shape is taken from another image read from binary file
shape = tf.shape(tf.constant(np.ones([3, 3]).astype('float32')))

# create empty image but set (x,y) = 1
mask = tf.zeros(shape)
mask[x, y] = 1
```

Which fails due to a TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

**Attempt 1**

```
tmp = np.zeros([3, 3])
tmp[x, y] = 1
mask = tf.constant([tmp.tolist()])
```

First I thought it might be a good approach to create a numpy array with the desired data and then turn it into a tensor with tf.constant(). But this leads to the problem, that I can't use the Tensors x, y for indexing. This is because at creation time these are merely placeholders for the data to be read from the database (same problem would apply when I want to read the size 3x3 from the binarydata). Please note, that running the tensors x and y in a session to get the values is *not* a solution for me, because I need the data to train a network. So its necessary to acquire and process all the data within a single call of run.

**Attempt 2**

```
zero_tensor = tf.zeros(shape)
delta = tf.SparseTensor([[1, 1]], [1.0], [3, 3])
mask = zero_tensor + tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(delta)

sess = tf.Session()
mask_val = sess.run([mask])
print mask_val
```

Online I found a solution how to create a sparse tensor and use it to modify a tensor. Problem is, that the coordinates and shape of the mask need to be hardcoded and can't be taken at runtime from the tensor read.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there in your **attempt 2** !

The function `tf.SparseTensor()` or the better one `tf.sparse_to_dense(sparse_indices, output_shape, sparse_values)` (see the [doc.](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#sparse_to_dense)) allows you to take the data you read as `sparse_indices` and `output_shape`.

---

Here is the code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# coord read from binary file
x = tf.constant([1])
y = tf.constant([1])

# shape is taken from another image read from binary file
shape = tf.constant([3, 3])

# Little modification to get the right shape for the indices
sparse_indices = tf.transpose(tf.pack([x, y]))
mask = tf.sparse_to_dense(sparse_indices, shape, 1.)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped!